# Setting Vertical Scrollbar position in WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I've a datagrid in WPF, It has lots of records hence having a VerticalScrollBar, when i do some activity like delete in some where at bottom of the screen and after this activity set the first index of the row, First row has been selected but scrollbar remains at the same position(bottom). I want it to be at the top or wherever the selected row is.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you perform the delete, you can use a combination of UpdateLayout and ScrollIntoView DataGrid methods.  Ensure you call the UpdateLayout method before calling the ScrollIntoView method.