# how to change the default movement of scrollbar when the height of text box is greater than window height in case of MergedDataGrid?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, scrollbar, scrollviewer

I am using MergedDataGrid in which corresponding to one student we can have multiple courses assigned. When one student have been assigned large number of students than height of student name textbox increases and gets larger than window height. Now when i try to rename the Students Name than scrollbar moves to bottom automatically.I want to maintain the position of scrollbar.... while renaming the student name.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting Vertical Scrollbar position in WPF DataGrid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7555778/setting-vertical-scrollbar-position-in-wpf-datagrid)

Comment: If the question is about a DataGrid (not sure what a MergedDataGrid is), possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7555778/setting-vertical-scrollbar-position-in-wpf-datagrid